# Display default image, if it does not exist in the database with php

Tags: php

I made a condition that when there is no image in my database, I return a standard image, however, I am having a small problem in my syntax and I have not been able to find a solution so far.

The problem is that I am not able to pass my `$user['photo']` variable inside my echo

This is my code

```
if(!empty($imagem_de_perfil) == null) {
   echo '<img src="../../painel/public/images/no_image.png" alt="Imagem de perfil" width="160" height="120">';
} else {
   echo '<div style="background: url(<?= base_url() ?><?= $user['photo'] ?>); position: relative; left: 48%; background-size: 48px 48px; width: 48px; height: 48px;" class="upload_photo upload_photo_user">
  </div>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Escape the array value.

Comment: `echo '<div style="background: url(' . base_url() . $user['photo'] . '; position: relative; left: 48%; background-size: 48px 48px; width: 48px; height: 48px;" class="upload_photo upload_photo_user"></div>';`

Answer (score 1):

You could store default image path in database as default value in your image row, then query databse to get image path and with html and php show that image

```
<img src = "<?php echo $user['image']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($imagem_de_perfil) == null) {
   echo '<img src="../../painel/public/images/no_image.png" alt="Imagem de perfil" width="160" height="120">';
} else {
   $userImage = $user['photo'];
   echo "<div style='background: url(<?= base_url() ?><?= $userImage ?>); position: relative; left: 48%; background-size: 48px 48px; width: 48px; height: 48px;' class='upload_photo upload_photo_user'>
  </div>";
}
```